# How to throw an exception out of my java bean

Tags: java, exception, jsp, javabeans

I use a javaBean in my jsp-application to store form values. This is how I get my values into my bean. This code is part of my form.jsp

```
try {  
        <jsp:setProperty name="formparam" property="*" />  
}  
catch (Exception e){ error = true; }
```

I left the "<%" out to not break the code display on stackoverflow. Now I get my exception if for example one puts text in my age field so the type conversation throws an exception.

Now I would like to know if it is possible to throw an exception in the setter of my bean an catch it with the very same try-catch-block.

Example form my bean: (I know this doesn't even compile but I hope you get an idea of what I want)

```
public void setAge(int a) {  
    if (this.validAge(a))  
        age = a;  
    else  
        throw Exception;  
}
```

I hope I get my point across. Of cause it's possible to call the validAge()-function in my bean from the form.jsp to validate the value but if I could throw an Exception directly so that the form.jsp can catch it it would be so much slicker.

So long.
   mantuko

Comment: And what happened when you tried to do just that?

Comment: This is a poor design.  You should not be writing scriplet code like this in a JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) declare the exception to be thrown
2) "throw new Exception"

```
public void setAge(int a) throws Exception {
  if (this.validAge(a))
    age =a ;
  else 
    throw new Exception("...")
}
```

Comment: Damn I just missed the "throws Exception" part. Thx. This works well for me.

To clarify my situation a bit:

I am working on a task for my WebEngineering class and I'm just at the beginning. So I can't use JavaScript for validation because I am about to learn JSP. We don't use JSLT (whatever this is I'll read later :) ) and I just know that taglibs exist but I just don't know what they do and how to use them yet. So BalusC's answer is above my knowledge.
I came to my mind that scriptlets are probably not the way to go. But up to now I have no alternative.

Thx to everybody.

Answer (score 4):

Just let the method throw it and use the JSTL [`c:catch`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/catch.html) to handle it.

```
<c:catch var="error">
    <jsp:setProperty name="formparam" property="*" />
</c:catch>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <p>Error: ${error}</p>
</c:if>
```

That said, the JSP is the wrong place to do the validations. Rather submit the form to a `Servlet`, let the servlet delegate a business/action model which does the validation, collect all error messages in some sort of `Map` in request scope which you access in EL. Do in **no** way use scriptlets in JSP. [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) provides pretty [everything](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) you need in the core, fmt and function taglibs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer JavaScript validation methods associated with the onblur event for that text box.  Let JavaScript manage this for you, not Java Beans.